# Footer with jQuery document.write conflict?

Tags: jquery

Could someone explain why the footer of a page would have **both** the `script` tag **and** a `document.write` for loading jQuery?  I've taken over several web projects and am seeing this pattern everywhere.

I'm not a jQuery guru, but this is what it appears is happening:

1. The `script` tag is first so jQuery should be loaded.
2. A **second** `script` tag then uses `document.write` to load jQuery a second time.

This is the footer:

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/common/bower_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="/common/bower_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="/common/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Why list the script twice?

Answer (score 3):

That is because if google CDN is down, you load jquery script from your own domain.

```
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/common/bower_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
```

`window.jQuery` checks if jquery is loaded or not. If not, it loads it from `/common/bower_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Aaah... brilliant!  Thanks for explaining, Mohammed.